# Bash script for backup

Tags: shell-script

I have set up a bash script to make a backup of files from my desktop computer to an external USB drive. This way, all the most recent or new files are automatically copied.
This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=`whoami`
declare -A BACKUP_INFOS
BACKUP_INFOS=(
    [/media/samiel/Elements/samiel]="/mnt/archive/articoli /mnt/archive/cataloghi /mnt/archive/Documenti /mnt/archive/materiali /mnt/archive/Scaricati"
    [/media/samiel/Elements/Musica]="/mnt/archive/Musica/"
)
for dest_dir in "${!BACKUP_INFOS[@]}"
do
  mkdir -p "$dest_dir"
  src="${BACKUP_INFOS[$dest_dir]}"
  rsync -avuz --delete --delete-after --progress $src "$dest_dir"
done
```

Now, however, having also a laptop, I would like to set up another script where the most recent files from the desktop are copied to the laptop and the most recent files from the laptop to the desktop.
Do I simply have to "double" the commands, or is there a more elegant and functional way to achieve my goal?
Thanks

Comment: The gotcha in this kind of scenario is working out how to delete files without them coming back again. You may want to take a look at `unison` or one of its alternatives

Comment: Thanks for the report 1. I found the discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602324/how-do-i-synchronize-in-both-directions. 2. So, none of the solutions suggested there solve the problem of deleted files? 3. I need to synchronize a linux (ext4) and an apple pc. Are there any problems due to the difference in file systems?